# How to select multiple radio button added from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone help me with this problem I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. I have here the radio button I can select in one form but when I add another form then check the radio button the check will transfer to other radio button which I added. Here is the code

```js
$("#ha").click(function() {
  var tayo = "";
  tayo += '<div class="row">';
  tayo += '<div class="col-lg-12">';
  tayo += '<select class="handicap">';
  tayo += '<option value="">Select<\option>';
  tayo += '<option value="cb">TRUE or FALSE</option>';
  tayo += '</select>';
  tayo += '<div class="ahhh">';
  tayo += '<div class="inputs"></div>';
  tayo += '</div>';
  tayo += '</div>';
  tayo += '</div>';

  $("#cardsss").append(tayo);
  bindEvent();
});

function bindEvent() {
  $('.handicap').change(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "cb") {
      $(e.target).next('.ahhh').html('<br><div class="inputs"><input type="radio" name="true_false[]" value="true">TRUE<input type="radio" name="true_false[]" value="false">FALSE</div>');
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="cardsss">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <select class="handicap">
      <option>Select</option>
        <option value="cb">TRUE or FALSE</option>
      </select>
      <div class="ahhh">
        <div class="inputs"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="ha" class="fa fa-clone"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delegate
2. Add a Please select to allow the change event
3. You had true/true on your inputs

```js
$('#cardsss').on('change', '.handicap', function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == "cb") {
    $(e.target).next('.ahhh').html('<br><div class="inputs"><input type="radio" name="true_false[]" value="true">TRUE<input type="radio" name="true_false[]" value="false">FALSE</div>');
  }

});

$('#cardsss').on('click', '.ahhh input', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$("#ha").on("click", function() {
  const tayo = $("#cardsss div").eq(0).clone()
  $("#cardsss").append(tayo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div id="cardsss">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <select class="handicap">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="cb">TRUE or FALSE</option>
      </select>
      <div class="ahhh">
        <div class="inputs"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="ha" class="fa fa-clone"></a>
```